# setting up categories in view in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, e-commerce

I am building a online restaurant project through which user can order items. I have a sql table with id,item_name,item_image,item_price and category.
I want to display all items in my view category wise. 
My controller function is :-

```
public function order()
{
    if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in'))
    {
    $data['i']=$this->model_db->item_details();
    $this->load->view('order',$data);
}
else {
    redirect('main/login');
}
}
```

My model function is

```
public function item_details()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM items");
    return $query->result();
}
```

My view code is

```
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-xs-12 side-nav"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-10 main">

                    <?php
                    foreach ($i as $item) {
                        # code...

                    ?>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-4 <?php echo $item->category ?>">

                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-8 item">

                                <img src="<?php echo $item->img?>" width="200px" height="150px">

                        <p><?php echo $item->item_name?></p>
                        <p><?php echo $item->category?></p>
                        <p><?php echo $item->price?></p>

                        <p><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>main/add_to_cart/<?php echo $item->img?>/<?php echo $item->item_name?>/<?php echo $item->price?>" class="btn btn-danger">Place Order</a>
                        </form>

                    </div></div>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body  
</html>
```

I want to display all results above in view category wise.

Comment: i want to all sort all items an put them category wise.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible solutions. None of them is codeigniter specific.

Here's some untested code that should do what you want:

```
public function item_details()
{
    $items = array();
    $categories = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT(category) FROM items")->result();
    foreach($categories as $category)
    {
        $items[$data] = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM items WHERE category = ?', $category)->result();
    }
    return $items;
}
```

And you display it with the following in your view:

```
foreach ($i as $category => $item) {
    // display it ...
}
```

Comment: Which error? You're not a developer, right? Pay someone to do it ... that's easy stuff.